# Incremental indexing using Logstash from SQL Server to Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch, logstash-configuration, logstash-jdbc

Hi All I'am getting below error while running my logstash to index record from SQLserver database to elasticsearch

```
Java Version : 13
Logstash : 7.2.0
Elastic search :  7.2.0
JDBC Driver :  mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12-shaded
```

**MyConfig file**

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => "C:\Users\Mohan\Downloads\MsoftDriver\sqljdbc_7.4\enu\mssql-jdbc-7.4.1.jre12-shaded.jar"
jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-VHDBS6E\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=mohan;"
jdbc_user => "mohan"
jdbc_password => "mohan"
statement => "SELECT * FROM [User_Name]"
start_position=> "beginning"
}
}
filter {
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "http://localhost:9200"

index => "Employee"

}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

**Getting Below error**

```
 Failed to execute action {:action=>LogStash::PipelineAction::Create/pipeline_id:main, :exception=>"LogStash::ConfigurationError", :message=>"Something is wrong with your configuration.", :backtrace=>["C:/Users/Mohan/Desktop/EsearchKibana/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/config/mixin.rb:87:in `config_init'", "C:/Users/Mohan/Desktop/EsearchKibana/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/inputs/base.rb:60:in `initialize'", "org/logstash/plugins/PluginFactoryExt.java:258:in `plugin'", "org/logstash/plugins/PluginFactoryExt.java:120:in `buildInput'", "org/logstash/execution/JavaBasePipelineExt.java:50:in `initialize'", "C:/Users/Mohan/Desktop/EsearchKibana/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/java_pipeline.rb:24:in `initialize'", "C:/Users/Mohan/Desktop/EsearchKibana/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/pipeline_action/create.rb:36:in `execute'", "C:/Users/Mohan/Desktop/EsearchKibana/logstash-7.2.0/logstash-core/lib/logstash/agent.rb:325:in `block in converge_state'"]}
```

Could anyone please help me to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi all above issue is resolved for me i hope it is due to wrong JDBC driver. I have downloaded the JDBC client directly from below link instead of Microsoft and placed the file in

**\logstash-7.2.0\logstash-core\lib\jars**

https://www.elastic.co/downloads/past-releases/jdbc-client-7-2-0

Note : **My logstash version is 7.2.0**

**logstash config worked for incrementel indexing approach**

```
input {
jdbc {
jdbc_driver_library => ""
jdbc_driver_class => "com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver"
jdbc_connection_string => "jdbc:sqlserver://DESKTOP-VHDBS6E\SQLEXPRESS:1433;databaseName=xxxxx;"
jdbc_user => "xxxxx"
jdbc_password => ""xxxx
jdbc_paging_enabled => true
tracking_column => modified_date
use_column_value => true
clean_run => true
tracking_column_type => "timestamp"
schedule => "*/2 * * * * *"
statement => "SELECT * from [User_Name] where modified_date >:sql_last_value"
}
}

filter {
 mutate {
   remove_field => ["@version","@timestamp"]
 }
}

output {
elasticsearch {
hosts => "http://localhost:9200"
index => "employee"
document_type => "_doc"
document_id => "%{id}"

}
stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I hope this one help for those who is trying to process incremental indexing to Elasticsearch using logstash

Answer (score 2):

The error is because of start_position=> "beginning". please comment it and try once.

Answer (score 1):

Well, there is no such setting "start_position" for the jdbc-input plugin. Logstash can't recognize this setting and thus fails. Take a look at the [doc](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/logstash/7.2/plugins-inputs-jdbc.html) - you won't find it there.

Also, be aware that there is a bug in the jdbc-input-plugin with Java version 9 onwards (this would be the next issue with your configuration I guess). So please refer to this [github issue](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-jdbc_static/issues/47) and this [workaround](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-filter-jdbc_streaming/issues/34) when logstash fails because it can't load the jdbc driver.

Comment: Hi i will try this but i need some clarity i am using SQL server 2014 express edition and my Java version is 13. For this setup what should be my JDBC driver. any idea? I am facing issue with my JDBC driver too

Comment: Hi. I posted two links to that issue in my answer.

Comment: I have seen that trying the same keep you posted

Comment: I suggest that you open a new question about that particular issue since this question seems to be solved.